# Как можно вывести массив названий в атрибут title в Vue

Tags: vue.js

Как можно вывести массив названий countries в атрибут title, чтобы было title="France, Germany"?

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
   <td>
     <span :title="item.countries">{{item.name}}</span>
   </td>
</tr>

json:
items: [
   {
     name: 'item 1',
     countries: [{title: 'france'}, {title: 'germany'} ...]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          name: 'item 1',
          countries: [{ title: 'france' }, { title: 'germany' }],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getNames(countries) {
      return countries.map(i => i.title).join(', ');
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
<span :title="getNames(item.countries)">{{item.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```